Why is Gimp chopping off parts of an image
When I open an image in any of 3 image editors, the image is "chopped off."

My browser and android phone show it correctly.
How can I fix it?


@karel https://imgur.com/a/wn0Otxi

The cropped image in your link is not the same image as the image in the body text of your question (chop.jpg). The image in your link is 773.8 kB and the image in the GIMP screenshot is much larger (69.8 MB). This suggests that you may still have a backup copy of the original high resolution image before you chopped it stored somewhere else possibly with a different name.
Try searching for 20241003_062018.jpg in the messages in your Gmail inbox. Maybe it's still there if you haven't deleted the message where it came from. The message from Andrew K which contains the relevant image is titled (no subject). A similar but not identically named image is contained in another message from Andrew K titled Worm.

Thanks. I found the picture in the trash. I am glad I did not empty the trash like I do with yahoo mail.

I realized that Gimp did not "chop off parts of an image."
